# wget error unable to resolve host address ‘my-proxy.dmz’ in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wget

Does any one know how to solve this problem? Thanks so much!

```
Resolving my-proxy.dmz (my-proxy.dmz)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘my-proxy.dmz’
```

My system is Ubuntu and when I am normal user and use wget to get any web will show this error message.
But when I am root, wget works fine. I do not know what is 'my-proxy.dmz' mean.
This maybe a very little problem for your expert but I can not solve it.....

Thanks so much!

Best regards